# Get unique page view events for analytics

Tags: angular, web-analytics

I'm trying to connect an Angular 10 application to the analytics for the page views.

This is as far as I can get:

```
this.router.events.subscribe((event: any) => {
  if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
    this.analyticsService.sendPageView(event.urlAfterRedirects);
  }
});
```

The problem is that I get item views and not page views. For example, for the route `/item/:id` it will generate a different url for each item's `id`:

- /item/1234
- /item/5678
- ...

But this is essentially one page (a page to display a specific item) and shouldn't generate different path for the analytics.

I must get something like `/item/:id` without the parsed parameters.

Or maybe if I could retrieve the current component name?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to listen to the router events and get the path from the route snapshots. The component name is also accessible from the `event.snapshot.component` property but it's very likely that it will be minified in the production build.

```
const activationEnd$ = this.router.events.pipe(filter<ActivationEnd>(event => event instanceof ActivationEnd));
const navigationEnd$ = this.router.events.pipe(filter<NavigationEnd>(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd));
activationEnd$
  .pipe(
    map(event => event.snapshot.routeConfig.path),
    buffer(navigationEnd$),
    map(paths => paths.reverse().join('/')),
    distinctUntilChanged()
  )
  .subscribe(path => this.analyticsService.sendPageView(path));
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-basic-example-kb3kgu?file=app/app.component.ts)

Comment: This solution works very well for  1 level of routing. But with some modifications I made it work for multi level routing like: /user/organization
Because otherwise sendPageView() will get call multiple times. One for "user" and another for "organization".

Comment: What needs to be done for the perfect solution:
- Listening for the "NavigationStart" to reset an array of string.
- Stacking the path to this array for each "ActivationEnd" events.
- And finally with the last "NavigationEnd" event I can combine the array in one string.

Comment: Very good point. I think we can leverage the `buffer` function of RxJS to make it easier. Please check out the edited answer and demo.